# Number formatting in Grafana

Tags: grafana

I have a number in Grafana that I'd like to format as "km". But, as soon as the value is higher than 1 000, it's formattet as 1,1 Mm instead of 1 100 km.

I can't find how to always show it as km.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, Grafana tries to create the shortest number by default, so it uses SI prefixes. Try to create custom `km` unit (not default SI km for length):

[image]

It is not clear what kind of panel type/Grafana version you are using, so it may not be a solution, because some panel types/older Grafana versions may implement it differently.